# MediaWiki - Search for text in uploaded files

Tags: elasticsearch, mediawiki

Goal is to index uploaded files and search for text within them.

Current setup:

- MediaWiki 1.27
- PostgreSQL 9.4
- Elasticsearch 1.7.5
- MW-Extension CirrusSearch 1.27
- MW-Extension Elastica (master)

The search with Elasticsearch in wiki-pages and for uploaded files is working. But what do I have to do to index and search for text within the uploaded files (pdf, doc, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a media handler which can extract the text; see [MediaHandler::getEntireText](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classMediaHandler.html#ac2bfa172ab3a6643661d14d29eb96012). For PDF [PdfHandler](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PdfHandler) does it; I imagine extensions exist for other common formats as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used this [plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/mapper-attachments.html) . One disadvantage of it that it is using too much space, so later in my project we migrated to use [tika](http://tika.apache.org/) (.net port version) which is used by mapper plugin.